# Vector of only ones by activating the bits

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Take any binary vector of length $4n+1$ with $n\geqslant0$. We can activate any bits. When a bit is activated, neighboring bits change their values $0$ -> $1$, $1$ -> $0$. Our goal is to turn the original binary vector into a vector of only ones by activating the bits.

Then I conjecture that if the value of the binary vector belongs to [A158705](https://oeis.org/A158705), this is possible for a maximum of $4n+1$ activations. Here [A158705](https://oeis.org/A158705) is nonnegative integers with an odd number of even powers of $2$ in their base-$2$ representation.

Similarly for any binary vector of length $4n+3$ with $n\geqslant0$ I conjecture that if the value of the binary vector belongs to [A158704](https://oeis.org/A158704), this is possible for a maximum of $4n+3$ activations. Here [A158704](https://oeis.org/A158704) is nonnegative integers with an even number of even powers of $2$ in their base-$2$ representation.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Of course it is possible with that many activations, why on Earth would you ever activate anything twice? See also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html

Comment: @domotorp It is possible with that many activations only if it is possible at all; if the length is $3k + 2$ (i.e. if $n$ is 1 mod 3), then it may not be possible at all. For example, consider $n = 1$ with the zero-vector.

Comment: @domotorp, thank you for comment! Very interesting link indeed.